# Find once and return different strings replaced with different words

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, optimization, replace

```
const str = 'i love code. i write code everyday.'
const regex = /code/g

const outputJs   = str.replace(regex, 'js'  )
const outputCss  = str.replace(regex, 'css' )
const outputHtml = str.replace(regex, 'html')
```

Here I am searching for `/code/g` three times and replacing with different strings.

Is there any way to optimize this code?

Because if the regex gets complicated and the str is very long then the javascript engine will take some time to search for the same thing again and again just to replace with a different word.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

**EDIT:** A workaround would be:

1. Generate a set of template strings using the regex.exec(str) and some string manipulation.
2. Use those template strings to generate output by concatenating replacement strings in-between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is critical, there may be an optimization you can perform using string templates, provided you can constrain your inputs to a finite set of predictable patterns.  For example, in your sample code, you are replacing a string literal that occurs twice in your text, but could occur an unknown number of times in other text.  If you can be sure that literal occurs, say, 0 to 10 times, then you can write 11 templates and select the appropriate one.

```js
    function interleave(list,word) {
      switch (list.length) {
       case 1:
        return `${list[0]}`; 
       case 2:
        return `${list[0]}${word}${list[1]}`; 
       case 3:
        return `${list[0]}${word}${list[1]}${word}${list[2]}`; 
        // add as many cases as you need
       default:
        return list.join(word);
      }
    }

    let outputJs, outputCss, outputHtml;
    let orig='i love code. i write code everyday.';

    const startTime = Date.now();

    let fragments=orig.split(/\bcode\b/);
    for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        outputJs = interleave(fragments,'js');
        outputCss = interleave(fragments,'css');
        outputHtml = interleave(fragments,'html');
    }

    const endTime = Date.now();
    console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
    console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
    console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
    console.log(`time: ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
```

Adding the improvement `AvisekDas` mentioned in the comments below (to allow people to run and verify the performance gain).

```js
function interleave(list,word) {
    let v=list[0];
    for (let i=1; i<list.length; i++) {
        v+=word+list[i];
    }
    return v;
}

let outputJs, outputCss, outputHtml;
let orig='i love code. i write code everyday.';

const startTime = Date.now();

let fragments=orig.split(/\bcode\b/);
for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    outputJs = interleave(fragments,'js');
    outputCss = interleave(fragments,'css');
    outputHtml = interleave(fragments,'html');
}

const endTime = Date.now();
console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
console.log(`time: ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
```

Comment: That is a serious optimization which makes a huge difference.

Comment: Didn't expect `arr.join()` to be that much unoptimized.

Comment: Instead of using template literals I'd prefer using regular string concatenation (`+` operator) as this is slightly faster and more readable in this use case.

Comment: You've just implemented `arr.join()`, but this time it's not unoptimized. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yeah, it makes me curious what happens in the native `arr.join()` that takes up so much relative time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a split, and work on the array to do the replace:

```js
const str = 'i love code. i write code everyday.';
let outputJs;
let outputCss;
let outputHtml;
let startTime = new Date();
for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  outputJs = [];
  outputCss = [];
  outputHtml = [];
  str.split(/\b(code)\b/).forEach(item => {
    if(item === 'code') {
      outputJs.push('js');
      outputCss.push('css');
      outputHtml.push('html');
    } else {
      outputJs.push(item);
      outputCss.push(item);
      outputHtml.push(item);
    }
  });
  outputJs = outputJs.join('');
  outputCss = outputCss.join('');
  outputHtml = outputHtml.join('');
}
console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
console.log('time: ' + (new Date() - startTime) + ' ms');
```

Output:

```
outputJs:   i love js. i write js everyday.
outputCss:  i love css. i write css everyday.
outputHtml: i love html. i write html everyday.
time: 1652 ms
```

In my test 1,000,000 runs took 1652 ms.

Now let's compare that to distinct replaces:

```js
const str = 'i love code. i write code everyday.';
let outputJs;
let outputCss;
let outputHtml;
let startTime = new Date();
for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  outputJs = str.replace(/\b(code)\b/g, 'js');
  outputCss = str.replace(/\b(code)\b/g, 'css');
  outputHtml = str.replace(/\b(code)\b/g, 'html');
}
console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
console.log('time: ' + (new Date() - startTime) + ' ms');
```

Output:

```
outputJs:   i love js. i write js everyday.
outputCss:  i love css. i write css everyday.
outputHtml: i love html. i write html everyday.
time: 494 ms
```

In my test 1,000,000 runs took 494 ms. As you can see this is 5 times faster, e.g. the split method does make it slower. Regular expressions are highly optimized, only in corner cases it is worth looking for alternatives.

Note that I added the word boundary `\b` in the regex on purpose to avoid false positives in your input string such as `codex`, `isocodeine`, `postcode`, `sarcoderm`

Comment: You're not accounting for the time the `.join('')` operations take

Comment: @peter complexity can be reduced a lot in here. You can split the str directly using the original regex `const parts = str.split(/code/g)`. Then for replacements you can use `parts.join('replacement_str')`.

Comment: @Bergi: good point, fixed

Comment: @AvisekDas: I added the word boundary `\b` on purpose to avoid false positives such as `codex`, `isocodeine`, `postcode`, `sarcoderm`

Comment: @AvisekDas: Any other questions? Care to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairer benchmark:

- Baseline

  ```js
  const str = 'i love code. i write code everyday.';
  let outputJs;
  let outputCss;
  let outputHtml;
  const startTime = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    outputJs = str.replace(/\bcode\b/g, 'js');
    outputCss = str.replace(/\bcode\b/g, 'css');
    outputHtml = str.replace(/\bcode\b/g, 'html');
  }
  const endTime = Date.now();
  console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
  console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
  console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
  console.log(`time: ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
  ```
- split once, join thrice:

  ```js
  const str = 'i love code. i write code everyday.';
  let outputJs;
  let outputCss;
  let outputHtml;
  const startTime = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    const parts = str.split(/\bcode\b/g);
    outputJs = parts.join('js');
    outputCss = parts.join('css');
    outputHtml = parts.join('html');
  }
  const endTime = Date.now();
  console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
  console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
  console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
  console.log(`time: ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
  ```
- split once, use forEach to replace, join by empty string (from @PeterThoeny's answer)

  ```js
  const str = 'i love code. i write code everyday.';
  let outputJs;
  let outputCss;
  let outputHtml;
  const startTime = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    const jsParts = [];
    const cssParts = [];
    const htmlParts = [];
    str.split(/\b(code)\b/).forEach(item => {
      if(item === 'code') {
        jsParts.push('js');
        cssParts.push('css');
        htmlParts.push('html');
      } else {
        jsParts.push(item);
        cssParts.push(item);
        htmlParts.push(item);
      }
    });
    outputJs = jsParts.join('');
    outputCss = cssParts.join('');
    outputHtml = htmlParts.join('');
  }
  const endTime = Date.now();
  console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
  console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
  console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
  console.log(`time: ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
  ```

Actually the original, simple code is the fastest. Regex engines are well-optimised.

Comment: your answer is correct but your benchmark is wrong. No need to split using regex everytime as the regex doesn't change. Only the replacement value changes. So move `const parts = str.split(/\bcode\b/g);` this line out of the `for` loop and see the result.

Comment: btw why are you guys adding those `\b`s to the regex?

Comment: @AvisekDas Ooops, I had copied over the regex with the `\b`s from Peter's answer. It's probably not necessary - but on the other hand, if you say you have a really complicated regular expression, you should test with that anyway and not with this toy example.

Comment: @AvisekDas Your question asks for code that splits once and then uses 3 different replacement values. The benchmarks do exactly that - in a loop with a lot of repetitions, so that the time is actually measurable (and random preemption is averaged out). You could obviously move the entire thing out of the loop since every iteration is computing the same result… but that's not the point.

Comment: @AvisekDas If you want to split your code into a "preparation" and a "replacement" part, and you wanted to measure only the latter, taking any amount of time up front, you could of course do that, but the question doesn't indicate this

Comment: This answer was mainly meant as a rebuttal to @PeterThoeny's post, that falsely claims an advantage for his approach. In any case, [you need to benchmark your actual code with the actual data in the actual target environment](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0):

If performance is critical, there may be an optimization you can perform using string templates, provided you can constrain your inputs to a finite set of predictable patterns.  For example, in your sample code, you are replacing a string literal that occurs twice in your text, but could occur an unknown number of times in other text.  If you can be sure that literal occurs, say, 0 to 10 times, then you can write 11 templates and select the appropriate one.

```js
    function interleave(list,word) {
      switch (list.length) {
       case 1:
        return `${list[0]}`; 
       case 2:
        return `${list[0]}${word}${list[1]}`; 
       case 3:
        return `${list[0]}${word}${list[1]}${word}${list[2]}`; 
        // add as many cases as you need
       default:
        return 'ERROR : No qualifying case found.';
      }
    }

    let outputJs, outputCss, outputHtml;
    let orig='i love code. i write code everyday.';

    const startTime = Date.now();

    let fragments=orig.split(/\bcode\b/);
    for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        outputJs = interleave(fragments,'js');
        outputCss = interleave(fragments,'css');
        outputHtml = interleave(fragments,'html');
    }

    const endTime = Date.now();
    console.log('outputJs:   ' + outputJs);
    console.log('outputCss:  ' + outputCss);
    console.log('outputHtml: ' + outputHtml);
    console.log(`time: ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
```